# Find out if date is between two dates, ignoring year

Tags: php, date

I need to determine if a date (month and day) is between two other month/days.

I've attached an image to this post that describes what I'm trying to do. Basically the example "current day" is highlighted in red, and it's between those nearest dates (Mar 15 and Nov 22). However, when I use Unix timestamps and artificially add a year to the dates, the script thinks that Nov 22 hasn't occurred yet, and therefore it suggests that Feb 1 is before Mar 15 AND Nov 22, instead of in between them.  So, I need to compare dates without using a year.

Hopefully this makes sense. I'd just like to compare dates using months and days, but ignoring the year, and using a framework like the wheel I show in the image.

[image: Determine if date falls between two dates]

Comment: Are you given which date is the beginning of the range and which is the end, or do you have to figure that out automatically?

Comment: You can format date to get only month and day and convert it to number of days. Or you can simply check two conditions, first month and then no of days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your example is that (in the same year) the upper bounding date is *before* the lower bound. In that case, Any date less than the upper bound (Jan 1 - Mar 14) or greater than the lower bound (Nov 23 - Dec 31) falls between the two.

```php
<?php
    $upperBound = new DateTime("Mar 15");
    $lowerBound = new DateTime("Nov 22");
    $checkDate = new DateTime("Feb 1");

    if ($lowerBound < $upperBound) {
        $between = $lowerBound < $checkDate && $checkDate < $upperBound;
    } else {
        $between = $checkDate < $upperBound || $checkDate > $lowerBound;
    }
    var_dump($between);
?>
```

Displays:
`boolean true`

### Edit

If the date you want to check is "Feb 29" and the current year is not a leap year, then DateTime interprets it as "Mar 1".

To check if a date falls between two dates, inclusively, use:

```
if ($lowerBound < $upperBound) {
    $between = $lowerBound <= $checkDate && $checkDate <= $upperBound;
} else {
    $between = $checkDate <= $upperBound || $checkDate >= $lowerBound;
}
```

Comment: This was spot on...thank you for the simple and powerful code!

Comment: If the date in question is Feb 29th and the current year is not a leap year, this will fail.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Thanks for pointing that out. If the current year isn't a leap year, then DateTime interprets Feb 29 as Mar 1.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can convert your dates to 4-digit numbers of the form MMDD.

```
$start = '1122';
$end = '0315';
$date = '0201';
```

If you don't yet have your dates formatted like this, you can use `date('md', $timestamp)`, or just calculate the number by taking `$month * 100 + $day`;

Then your test logic will change depending on whether you're crossing a year boundary or not. Putting it all together, it might look like this:

```
function isDateBetween($testM, $testD, $startM, $startD, $endM, $endD) {
    $start = $startM*100 + $startD;
    $end = $endM*100 + $endD;
    $date = $testM*100 + $testD;

    if ($start > $end) {
        // crossing a year boundary
        return ($date > $start) || ($date < $end);
    } else {
        // not crossing a year
        return ($date > $start) && ($date < $end);
    }
}
```

Here's some examples of calling this function:

```
// your example given above
isDateBetween(2, 1, 11, 22, 3, 15); // true

// ends the day after instead
isDateBetween(3, 16, 11, 22, 3, 15); // false

// reverse the dates in your example
isDateBetween(2, 1, 3, 15, 11, 22); // false

// ends the day after, with reversed dates
isDateBetween(3, 16, 3, 15, 11, 22); // true
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//must be 2 digit month, then 2 digit day, like mm-dd
$low  = '03-15';
$high = '11-22';
$date = '02-01';

$isBetween = $date >= $low && $date <= $high;
var_dump($isBetween);
```

I'm making use of lexicographic ordering, which is how php compares strings. The key point is to put the largest units on the left(months), and make sure to left-pad each numeric segment to the same length, using zeros to pad.

If you don't yet have your dates as strings formatted like this, you can use `date('m-d', $timestamp)` function to achieve that.

Comment: You can even drop the `-` and it just becomes a 4-digit number that can be safely compared like any other 4-digit number.

Comment: @jcsanyi very true, so long as it stays a string.

Comment: It shouldn't have to stay as a string. If they're converted to INTs, it'll still compare just fine.

Comment: But 02-01 is NOT >= 03-15, nor is 201 >= 315.

Comment: @Herbert You're right - I missed the part about crossing a year boundary in your original question. See my answer for a working solution instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this.

```
<?php
$check_date= strtotime("31-Aug-1990");
$start_date= strtotime("10-Aug-2013");
$end_date= strtotime("30-Aug-1990");

if (date("M-d", $check_date)>date("M-d", $start_date) && date("M-d", $check_date)<date("M-d", $end_date))
    echo "in the range";
else
    echo "not in the range";
```

Working code is [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a5y-7cm)