# Date between 2 other dates, disregarding year

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

I'm looking for something like the person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540268/find-out-if-date-is-between-two-dates-ignoring-year) was lookin for, only I'd like to use MySQL. The table below is something you'd find in my database (simplified).

```
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | name | first| last |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | John | 1020 | 0814 |
|    2 | Ram  | 0827 | 0420 |
|    3 | Jack | 0506 | 0120 |
|    4 | Jill | 0405 | 0220 |
|    5 | Zara | 1201 | 1219 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

First of all the entry has to be random, not id 4 and I only want 1 entry. I worked that out: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE id <> 4 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1`.

In this table the columns 'first' and 'last' are dates formatted as mmdd (both integers). So John is available for most of the year; from October 20th to August 14th. Zara on the other hand is only available for a small period of time; December 1st till December 19th.

My question: how do I change my query to only select the available people? I can't use 'between' since, in John's case, there's nothing between 1020 and 0814.

I just can't figure it out, there's must be other people that have a similar problem... Does anyone have a solution?

Kind regards

Comment: So `first` and `last` are stored as integers rather than dates? Why are some first-values after last-values? As this is the case, how would you know to search for first > last or last > first? I assume also that you meant October 20th.

Comment: You can use `BETWEEN` if you first convert your 'dates' to actual MySQL `DATE` values. You can do this with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date): `STR_TO_DATE(first, '%m%d')`. The problem @AndyG notes remains, though.

Comment: @GreatBigBore It's not enough to add 10000 to last. In the case of John, 0101 should be considered between 1020 and 0814, but it's not between 1020 and 10814.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish two cases.

1. When `first < last`, the dates are in the same year. You can then use `between` to match dates.
2. When `first > last`, it means `last` is in the next year. In this case, the dates that match are `date >= first OR date <= last`.

So your WHERE clause should be:

```
WHERE IF(first < last, @date BETWEEN first AND last,
                       @date >= first OR date <= last)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the special case be `BETWEEN last AND first`, since `last < first` in the special case?

Comment: @GreatBigBore There are no numbers between 1020 and 0814.

Comment: I did get the directions of my comparisons wrong, though. I've fixed it.

Comment: Ok, right. I was thinking that you meant to append the adjusted year value to the dates.

Comment: @ AnyG & Tomas Creemers: I thought of this but to my knowledge str_to_date() only formats the dates... Also then I'd have to add a year, since there is no field type that only saves mmdd... in my case there's just no year available since theoratically speaking this goes on for ever.

@Barmar So my query, when using php, would become: `SELECT * FROM test WHERE id <> 4 AND (IF(first < last, $date BETWEEN first AND last, $date >= first OR $date <= last)) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1`. I'll look into IF-statements in SQL a bit more!

Thanks for your answers!